# Is it optimal to check a variable before setting it?

Tags: c, get, bitmap, set, byte

Is `if(foo) bar |= foo;` more optimal than just `bar |= foo;`?

Is reading data stored in a variable somehow faster than writing it (ignoring hardware-specific limitations) so it is actually worth to check it before performing some operation?

Comment: To be technically complete, there can exist rare circumstances in which the cost of writing to `bar` is such that testing `foo` beforehand is worthwhile. You will very likely not encounter such a circumstance until many years into your career, if ever.

Comment: That depends. Some cases: https://godbolt.org/z/dYd4qs But usually it is less efficient

Comment: It will be probably more efficient if memory write will require cache flush.

Comment: @0___________ I just wanted to say thanks for showing me that awesome site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `if(foo) bar |= foo;` more optimal than just `bar |= foo;`?

No, it's most likely far worse. The `if` you add creates a [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)) in your compiled program which degrades performance compared to the single branchless instruction.

In `if(foo) bar |= foo;` you are *at best* doing only 1 or 2 instructions (depending on the architecture): comparison and branching. At worst 2 or 3 instructions (again depending on the architecture): comparison, branching and bitwise OR. Instead, in `bar |= foo` you are always doing one instruction only. Of course, the compiler can optimize the code to some extent, but using the `if` here is nonetheless basically useless. And of course, the cost of a compare instruction could be less than the cost of a bitwise OR in some architecture, but the combination of comparison and conditional branching is almost certainly going to be more than the cost of a single bitwise OR.

> Is reading data somehow faster than writing (ignoring hardware-specific conditions) so it is actually worth to check it before performing some specific operation on that variable?

The problem is not really reading or writing data (which will most likely be in a CPU register anyway for that single operation), but performing 2/3 instructions instead of 1, while also branching. Branching further degrades performance because in modern CPUs which use branch predictors it can (to make it simple) cause the CPU cache to be flushed away, therefore needing to re-read the code a second time. See [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)

Doing something like `if (cond) { statements; }` is only useful if the cost of evaluating `cond` plus branching is significantly less than the cost of the `statements;` executed conditionally. For a single simple mathematical instruction, this is almost never the case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. All I could find online was "it depends on the speed of your cpu/ram/hd, etc". Nothing on a compiler/instruction level.

Answer (score 1):

In theory:

It depends what processor you are running (how fast a compare is vs how vast bit operations are). It also depends how often `foo` will be 0. If never then you gain nothing (and actually slow it down)

In reality:

Unless you need to do this 100 million times on stressed out hardware (think realtime embedded) it makes no difference.

Comment: I'm writing a memory allocation function on a kernel, so I guess that would be the case for me. Thanks for your answer!